# Three select elements updates depending on each other

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

can anyone help me to solve this issue , its driving me crazy.

- I have three select elements ,
- the first one is named "level1" , second is "level2" ,third is "level3"
- All of them will get the result from post.php which calls querys from the database.
- "level1" will load once the page is loaded , and will show all records with level1
- "level2" is hidden , once onchange level1 , it will be shown and load all level2 records based on level1 value.
- "level3" same process and will depends on level2 value.

**Problem**

- Post is been called twice when i check in the Network tab of chrome.
- I can see the result i want in the response tab of the post in Network tab, but it keep showing the wrong data.

kindly check the pictures attached.
Also attached my code.
im using ajax and jquery.
Appreciate your quick response.
Thanks
Azzam.

result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9Yco.png

```
$.post('post.php',{selected: $('#level1').val()},
function(response){$('#level1').html(response); }  
      );

function getlevel2(){       
    $.ajax({
        type:'post',
        url: 'post.php',
        data: $('#level1'),
        success: 
$.post('post.php',{selected: $('#level1').val()},
function(data)
{$(document).ready(function(){$('#level2').html(data);})})});}





<form>
  <select name="level1" id="level1" onchange="getlevel2(this.value)" multiple size=10></select>
  <select name="level2" id="level2" onchange="getlevel3(this.value)" multiple size=10></select>
  <select name="level3" id="level3" onchange="" multiple size=10></select>

<input type="image" value="submit" src="addtocart.png" alt="submit Button" onMouseOver="this.src='addtocart.png'" width="10%">

</form>
<div id="search_results" style="display:inline"></div>
```

**post.php**

```
<?php
include ("config.php");

$getcats = mysql_Query("select * from categories where level=1 order by tid ASC");

if ($_POST['level1'] != 0)
    {
    $getlevel2 = mysql_query("select * from categories where catID=$level1 and level=2");
    while ($level2Arr = mysql_Fetch_array($getlevel2))
        {
        echo "<option value=$level2Arr[tid]>$level2Arr[catName]</option>";
        }
    }
  else
    {
    while ($catsArr = mysql_fetch_array($getcats))
        {
        echo "<option value=$catsArr[tid]>$catsArr[catName]</option>";
        }
    } 
?>
```

Comment: Calling `$.post` on `$.ajax` with the same values makes no sense. And please add all your additional codes in the question itself, **not** in comments.

Comment: $(document).ready function will not fire in $.post method as DOM is already loaded....

Comment: Should your data be $('#level1').val() instead of $('#level1') ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this might help, for any help let me know

```
//dom ready
$(function(){

    $.post('post.php',{selected: $('#level1').val()},function(response){
      $('#level1').html(response); 
    });

    $("#level1").change(function(){
        $.ajax({
        type:'post',
        url: 'post.php',
        data: {selected:$('#level1').val()},
        success: function(html){
                $("#level2").html(html);
            }
        });
    });

    $("#level2").change(function(){
        $.ajax({
        type:'post',
        url: 'post.php',
        data: {selected:$('#level2').val()},
        success: function(html){
                $("#level3").html(html);
            }
        });
    });
})



<form>
  <select name="level1" id="level1" multiple size=10></select>
  <select name="level2" id="level2"  multiple size=10></select>
  <select name="level3" id="level3"  multiple size=10></select>

<input type="image" value="submit" src="addtocart.png" alt="submit Button" onMouseOver="this.src='addtocart.png'" width="10%">

</form>
<div id="search_results" style="display:inline"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response , i applied the code you recommended but unfortunately im still getting all levels  with same value of level 1 .. any other adivce ?

Comment: Problem Solved .. Thanks Pankah you really helped me . Im new in Jquery and ajax , appreciate your professional support.

Comment: Actually I posted the post.php in my question you can scroll up. Your code is correct , but I had to use $(#level2) instead of using $($level2).val(). !! it looks strange but i worked .. well this affect my application performance ?